# powershell core error: The specified module 'RPC-Client' was not loaded

Tags: xml, linux, powershell, .net-core, xml-rpc

How do I find out more information about `xml-rpc` for `powershell`?

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> Update-Help                     
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> Get-Help Send-XmlRpcRequest     
Get-Help: Get-Help could not find Send-XmlRpcRequest in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.       PS /home/nicholas>                                                                                                                  PS /home/nicholas> Get-Host | Select-Object Version                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Version                                                                                                                             -------                                                                                                                             
7.1.0

PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> exit
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

As I ran `Update-help` I'd expect to find [more](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ao832d/how_to_consume_xmlrpc_web_services/) information.

perhaps add a [module](https://github.com/mosserlee/PSClient-for-XML-RPC)?

I tried:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ pwsh hello.ps1 
Import-Module: /home/nicholas/powershell/hello.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  import-module RPC-Client
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The specified module 'RPC-Client' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

hello
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ cat hello.ps1 
import-module RPC-Client 


"hello"
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$
```

How do I add that into `powershell` core?

I tried to install as:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Find-Module -Name Xml

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
7.0                  Xml                                 PSGallery            A module providing converters for HTML to XML, vario…

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Find-Module -Name Rpc
Find-Package: /snap/powershell/149/opt/powershell/Modules/PowerShellGet/PSModule.psm1:8879
Line |
8879 |          PackageManagement\Find-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Rpc'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all
     | available registered module repositories.

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Find-Module -Name foo
Find-Package: /snap/powershell/149/opt/powershell/Modules/PowerShellGet/PSModule.psm1:8879
Line |
8879 |          PackageManagement\Find-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'foo'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all
     | available registered module repositories.

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Find-Module -Name Rpc-Client
Find-Package: /snap/powershell/149/opt/powershell/Modules/PowerShellGet/PSModule.psm1:8879
Line |
8879 |          PackageManagement\Find-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Rpc-Client'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all
     | available registered module repositories.

PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

but perhaps need to "download" it first?  Something [like](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/installing-modules-in-powershell-core-on-linux):

```
sudo powershell -Command {Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Netcore}
```

or at least along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) functionality built into PowerShell.

Providing such functionality therefore requires third-party code.

In your case, it seems your script requires the [`XmlRpc` module](https://github.com/lipkau/XmlRpc/blob/master/XmlRpc.psd1), available from the PowerShell Gallery [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/XmlRpc) (which means you can install it with `Install-Module XmlRpc`).

However, this module was last updated more than 5 years ago, predating PowerShell's cross-platform edition, [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), so you'll have to find out yourself if it works on a Unix-like platform such as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

from mklement0:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Install-Module XmlRpc

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by 
running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
PS /home/nicholas/powershell>         
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Get-Help xmlrpc
```

> Name                              Category  Module
> Synopsis                                                      ----
> --------  ------                    --------                                                      ConvertTo-XmlRpcMethodCall        Function  XmlRpc
> …
> ConvertTo-XmlRpcType              Function  XmlRpc
> …
> Send-XmlRpcRequest                Function  XmlRpc
> …

```
                                                                                                                                                                                   PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

looks promising.