# Hello World for Powershell Send-XmlRcpRequest?

Tags: xml, powershell, .net-core, xml-rpc, read-eval-print-loop

Desired [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
        <value><string>South Dakota</string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

---

How do I use the `xml-rpc` powershell [module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64850281/4531180) to view the response?

Perhaps it's possible to "cat" or somehow pipe the [result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64874396/4531180) from `baidu` to something that will print it?  Or, put it into an object?

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Send-XmlRpcRequest -Url "http://ping.baidu.com/ping/RPC2" -MethodName "weblogUpdates.extendedPing" -Params @('jdon')                             

xml                            methodResponse
---                            --------------
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" methodResponse

PS /home/nicholas/powershell>
```

or the more full request:

```
Send-XmlRpcRequest -Url "http://ping.baidu.com/ping/RPC2" -MethodName "weblogUpdates.extendedPing" -Params @('jdon','http://www.jdon.com/','http://www.jdon.com/47686','http://www.jdon.com/rss')
```

generates a similar result.  Something [like](https://www.example-code.com/powershell/http_xmlrpc.asp):

```
$http = New-Object Chilkat.Http

$xmlReq = "<?xml version=`"1.0`"?><methodCall><methodName>demo.sayHello</methodName><params /></methodCall>"

$xmlResponse = $http.XmlRpc("http://www.cknotes.com/xmlrpc.php",$xmlReq)
if ($http.LastMethodSuccess -ne $true) {
    $($http.LastErrorText)
    exit
}

$($xmlResponse)
```

except, with [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/XmlRpc/1.0.1.1) module, where is the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is really **"How do I convert an xml document to a string with nice and readable formatting"** - the answer to which might look something like this:

```
function Convert-XmlToString
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [xml]$Xml
  )

  begin {
    # Create formatting settings
    $writerSettings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]@{Indent = $true; OmitXmlDeclaration = $true}

    # Create StringBuilder
    $stringBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
  }

  process {
    try {
      # Create XmlWriter
      $xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create($stringBuilder, $writerSettings)

      # Write xml document to XmlWriter
      $xml.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter)

      # Flush XmlWriter to output target (ie. the stringbuilder)
      $xmlWriter.Flush()

      # Output resulting string
      $stringBuilder.ToString()
    }
    finally{
      # Clean up
      $xmlWriter.Dispose()
      $stringBuilder = $stringBuilder.Clear()
    }
  }
}
```

With which you should be able to do something like:

```
PS C:\> $xmlRPCResponse = Send-XmlRpcRequest -Url "http://ping.baidu.com/ping/RPC2" -MethodName "weblogUpdates.extendedPing" -Params @('jdon','http://www.jdon.com/','http://www.jdon.com/47686','http://www.jdon.com/rss')  
PS C:\> $xmlRPCResponse |Convert-XmlToString
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
        <value><string>South Dakota</string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Is there better URL and example parameter to test?  Just to consume a response, or print it, really.  as above.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders Sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: it's okay, you answered the q, thank you.  just looking for a more interesting example.  no worries.

Answer (score 0):

this is close:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $xmlRPCResponse = Send-XmlRpcRequest -Url "http://ping.baidu.com/ping/RPC2" -MethodName "weblogUpdates.extendedPing" -Params @('jdon','http://www.jdon.com/','http://www.jdon.com/47686','http://www.jdon.com/rss')  
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $xmlRPCResponse | ConvertTo-Xml -As String                                                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                              
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Xml.XmlDocument">System.Xml.XmlDocument</Object>
</Objects>
PS /home/nicholas>
```

although not quite the desired output.

thanks to Mathias, and see:

[Powershell: Convert XML to String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15410455/4531180)

---

better result:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $xmlRPCResponse.OuterXml                  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><int>0</int></value></param></params></methodResponse>
PS /home/nicholas>
```

although kind of a useless example.  seems to work.

Comment: That's definitely _not_ what you want - as you can see it has reduced the response object to the string `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, you've lost all the information you're trying to inspect :)

Comment: used the dot operator?  seems okay.

Comment: No I'm talking about `ConvertTo-Xml`

Comment: right.  doesn't `$xmlRPCResponse.OuterXml` visually "print" the `xml` to the console?

Comment: Yes, `$OuterXml` is indeed the string-representation of the xml document in question, so that'll work (although it won't format it nicely)